# Why is it faster to do four simple selects instead of one select with left joins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I need to find a single value from a table `A` containing three foreign keys to two other tables `B` and `C`.

For the sake of experiment, I tested two ways to query the value:

**Multiple queries:**

```
declare @start int = (select top 1 [Id] from [B] where [Day] = '2015-01-01')
declare @end int = (select top 1 [Id] from [B] where [Day] = '2017-06-14')
declare @category int = (select top 1 [Id] from [C] where [Title] = 'Hello, World!')

select top 1 [Name]
from [A]
where [StartId] = @start
    and [EndId] = @end
    and [CategoryId] = @category
    and [Day] = '2016-05-27'
```

**Single query:**

```
select top 1 [Name]
from [A]
left join [B] as [BStart] on [BStart].[Id] = [A].[StartId]
left join [B] as [BEnd] on [BEnd].[Id] = [A].[EndId]
left join [C] on [C].[Id] = [A].[CategoryId]
where [BStart].[Day] = '2015-01-01'
    and [BEnd].[Day] = '2017-06-14'
    and [C].[Title] = 'Hello, World!'
    and [A].[Day] = '2016-05-27'
```

I was surprised that the execution plan indicates that the single query is more expensive than multiple queries. When doing all five `select`s together, the one with `left join`s indicates 53%. The other four queries indicate 12% each.

Those are the execution plans:

```
declare @start int = (select top 1 [Id] from [B] where [Day] = '2015-01-01')`
```

[image]

```
declare @end int = (select top 1 [Id] from [B] where [Day] = '2017-06-14')
```

(Same as below)

```
declare @category int = (select top 1 [Id] from [C] where [Title] = 'Hello, World!')
```

[image]

```
select top 1 [Name]
from [A]
where [StartId] = @start
    and [EndId] = @end
    and [CategoryId] = @category
    and [Day] = '2016-05-27'
```

[image]

```
select top 1 [Name]
from [A]
left join [B] as [BStart] on [BStart].[Id] = [A].[StartId]
left join [B] as [BEnd] on [BEnd].[Id] = [A].[EndId]
left join [C] on [C].[Id] = [A].[CategoryId]
where [BStart].[Day] = '2015-01-01'
    and [BEnd].[Day] = '2017-06-14'
    and [C].[Title] = 'Hello, World!'
    and [A].[Day] = '2016-05-27'
```

[image]

Why is the single query with `left join`s slower than the first approach?

Comment: A `top(n)` without an `order by` returns the first N number of rows ramdom. How big are the tables ?

Comment: Your where clause converts all your "left" joins to inner joins BTW.

Comment: I haven't mentioned that `[B].[Day]` and `[C].[Title]` have an unique index, which means that the lack of `order by` doesn't make the result non-deterministic.

Comment: As an aside: I've intermittently hit scenarios where a *union* ran more slowly than individual selects.  After a bit of experimentation, I determined that sometimes the query planner decides not to parallelize a union, causing CPU-bound queries to take far more time (though slightly less total CPU time).  And CPU-bound queries are not so uncommon if your query is running entirely in RAM.  Not what happened to you, but worth noting because SQL can be very finicky about deciding whether to parallelize, even with queries that are semantically very similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your execution plan for the "individual queries" shows that pre-calculating the StartID, Category etc allows an index to be used efficiently on A, "seeking" straight to the record(s) you want (you have a Non-Clustered Index Seek in your query plan), having identified the given Category etc to search for.

The "single-query" with JOINs, on the other hand, needs to carry out the join between table A-B-C "on the fly" before returning the "top 1" result matching your criteria. This join will involve all the records of those tables where they match to the other related table (full clustered index scan).

If you are frequently querying by Day and Title like this, it looks like an index is missing (or statistics out of date) that allow table B and C to be searched by those criteria.

By the way, Top 1 will only give a deterministic result if you "order by" some criteria (or if your search statement is unique) - otherwise you will get the 1st row the query comes to, which may or may not be consistent between occasions when you run it.